# Login not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, session, redirect

I have a login script from where after successful login I set the session variable and  redirect the user to homepage  and I am using the following script for redirect.

```
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function redirectWindow()
{setTimeout(function() {window.location.href=\"http://homepage.com\";},
3000);}window.onload = redirectWindow();</script>";
```

However the session variable $_SESSION is not getting set the first time and its values are not available on the homepage.But if I try to login again the $_SESSION values are then available on the homepage after the redirect.

This issue is not there if I remove the redirect. Is there any issue with the redirect script which may be causing old cached page getting loaded for the first time.

Comment: Why do you use a `<script>`? Can't you use `header('Location:...);` for the redirection?

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't have js enabled? Something to bear in mind.

Comment: @aurbano I cannot use header as I need to display successful login message which I echo before the redirect.

Comment: @ScottMcGready in that case the user can click on the home link, this just automates the redirect process.

Comment: How are you actually setting the `$_SESSION` vars? Can we see that code please

Comment: Ok, I found out the issue, it was because I was redirecting to         "h t t p :/ / homepage . com" and the initial page opened was "h t t p :/ /www .homepage. com" because of which I think the session variables were not available. Thanks everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the issue, it was because I was redirecting to "h t t p :/ / homepage . com" and the initial page opened was "h t t p :/ /www .homepage. com" because of which I think the session variables were not available. Thanks everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be doing is, after submission of the login form, loading a page with a little Javascript, then the client redirects to the new page.

Instead of trying to redirect with Javascript, why not use PHP:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/new_page.php' ) ;
```

This way, the redirect takes place as soon as the form is submitted.

Comment: I cannot use header as I need to display successful login message which I echo before the redirect.

Comment: In the future, it's helpful to say something like that in your question. Saves us the time of answering a question with something you've already tried/considered. In any case, you could pass your login message in the session - the new page could check for it and echo it on the new page instead.

Comment: You can use header with a delay, try this... header( "Refresh:5; url=example.com");